# Thoughts on Chromium based desktop app?

Tags: html, desktop, chromium, financial, openfin

Has anyone tried OpenFin? What are its pros and cons?

In terms of Development effort, stability, development support, maintenance, performance, memory footprint.

Answer (score -2):

I am part of the OpenFin Dev team and I have to say in terms of Development effort we are always improving our development tools, and have a large collection of example code that tackles some of the popular scenarios, we also have a yeoman generator that makes it super easy to get started: https://github.com/openfin/generator-openfin

In regards of stability, we ship a mayor release twice a year and you can chose to stick to a particular version at an application level. each deployed application can choose a particular version and it only takes a change in the server to have the clients updated on next app start.

Development support is highly active and we will work with you to resolve any issues. as I mentioned above we have created example code for popular scenarios.

Maintenance, would be similar to any web application without the need to support multiple browser versions, additionally we provide API's to create Windows installers for any OpenFin application.

Performance, you get all of the benefits of the V8 engine for JavaScript and the Blink layout engine. you also get API calls to monitor CPU and Memory.

Memory footprint, The OpenFin Runtime will create processes for each application and has several internal processes of its own, the actual footprint depends on what features you are using.

You can see a feature comparison between OpenFin and other solutions here https://openfin.co/runtime/compare/